# Searching Multiple Tumblr Tags

Tags: tumblr

I know that say one wanted to search for posts tagged with *#LOL* you can use the following,

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/lol

and for *#GIF* you can use

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/gif

A tag with a space could be for example, Emma Watson

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/emma+watson

*So my question is, if I want to search for #LOL and #GIF how can I accomplish this task?*

It seems that just `lol gif` returns

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/lol+gif

But I do not think this is right / I am not exactly sure what is the query here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You have the correct syntax. But its current architecture only allows multiple tag browsing when the tags are single words. It will break or return nothing if you try and combine tags where at least one consists of more than one word.

Valid for "food" and "pizza":

```
http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/food+pizza
```

No hope for "paper art" and "stars"

```
http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/paper+art+stars
```

Comment: From what I can tell, searching for `food+pizza` will not return posts tagged with `food` and `pizza`, but only those tagged with `food pizza` as a single tag.

Answer (score 0):

/tagged/FIRST-TAG?from_tag=SECOND-TAG

^ [Edit: this actually does not work. It only searches the FIRST-TAG. This url format appears when you click the 'related tags' section; perhaps tumblr uses it to rank the relevance of the related tags (hence the 'from_tag'). In short, tumblr doesn't have the desired tag searching capability.]

Comment: Seems like a good answer but it's rather short. Perhaps you can add some additional information, do some styling, make it more attractive. Read the [faq] area to know more about given answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google to search tumblr with multiple tags, like so:

> Pizza OR food OR stars tumblr

or

> site: tumblr pizza stars food

Comment: Can you give us an example URL of how this looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, [you can’t search multiple tags at once](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/using_tags#multiple):

> ### Can I search for multiple tags at once?
>
> No, that’s not supported.

Comment: Is this answer any better than the one already accepted?